# What is the equivalent html attribute of KnockoutJs's WITH in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, knockout.js

My currently using AngularJs and as I've used KnockoutJs in the past, I would like to use a similar attribute to KnockoutJs's `with` attribute but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. My AngularJs $scope currently looks something like this

```
$scope.data = {
    selectedCountry: ...,
    ...
};
```

now selectedCountry is a JS object and in the HTML I would like to be able to do something like this

```
<div with="data.selectedCountry">
  <div ng-bind="name"/>
  <div ng-bind="prop1"/>
  <div ng-bind="prop2"/>
<div>
```

instead of having to do what I'm currently doing, which is

```
<div>
  <div ng-bind="data.selectedCountry.name"/>
  <div ng-bind="data.selectedCountry.prop2"/>
  <div ng-bind="data.selectedCountry.prop3"/>
<div>
```

is there a way to do this in AngularJs? Any help would be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: The really short answer is that there's no equivalent to `with`. The only thing that comes close is `ngController`.

Answer (score 5):

The closest to that would be `ng-init` directive.

```
<div ng-init="c = data.selectedCountry">
    <div ng-bind="c.name"></div>
    <div ng-bind="c.prop1"></div>
    <div ng-bind="c.prop2"></div>
</div>
```

[Here is the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hQBtJe1eA1lcgVlmjzJB?p=preview)

Although its not exactly same as Knockout (where you don't need an alias), it should make your life easier since alias is better than writing the full navigation property path.

Comment: `ngInit` is definitely not the same as Knockout's `with`. In your example, you're just adding a new property to the scope.

Comment: Michael - Agreed. You were too quick for my edit. I just mentioned that in my answer. :) But ng-init I think will help Craig.

Comment: @KrishnaTejaVeeramachaneni +1. I made some edits to your code, to trim it to the "minimum" to convey the point ... hope that's acceptable!

Comment: @Scott Rippey. Absolutely. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have searched for this a lot. I found nothing better than just a trick:

You can simulate this functionality by this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [data.selectedCountry]">
  <div ng-bind="name"/>
  <div ng-bind="prop2"/>
  <div ng-bind="prop3"/>
<div>
```

TG.